# Xamarin Android search view in action bar is null

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I am having an issue where the ActionView property of a MenuItem that contains a SearchView is always null. I am targeting API level 22, I am trying to just use the built-in SearchView class from the Android.Support.V7.Widget package, and I am using a FragmentActivity.

One thing to note is in my application my actionbar works just fine and I'm able to set other menu items no problem.

For me when I inflate the menu I am getting the search menu item, but it's ActionView property is always null. I get the same behavior when I use the MenuItemCompat.GetActionView method.

Also, in the app I do not see the search icon at all, but instead I see the action bar context menu that has the "Search" label as an option.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here? My code snippets are below.

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:way="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        way:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        way:actionViewClass="Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

MyActivity.cs

```
namespace AndroidApp
{
    [Activity (Label = "WAY", Theme = "@style/AppTheme")]
    public class TabActivity : FragmentActivity, ActionBar.ITabListener, ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener
    {
        private SearchView SearchView;


        [A bunch of un-realted code]

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu (IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(this.CurrentMenuId, menu);

            IMenuItem item = menu.FindItem (Resource.Id.action_search);
            var sItem = MenuItemCompat.GetActionView (item);
            this.SearchView = sItem.JavaCast<SearchView> ();

            return true;
        }

        [More un-related code]
    }
}
```

Comment: Does anyone else have any ideas? Jraco11 response didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally figured out my problem. The problem was that I was trying to use the SearchView from the Support V7 package, but I had my API level set to 22. Changing my code to the following fixed the problem.

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/actionbar_button_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

MyActivity.cs

```
namespace AndroidApp
{
    [Activity (Label = "WAY", Theme = "@style/AppTheme")]
    public class TabActivity : FragmentActivity, ActionBar.ITabListener, ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener
    {
        private SearchView SearchView;


        [A bunch of un-realted code]

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu (IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(this.CurrentMenuId, menu);

            IMenuItem item = menu.FindItem (Resource.Id.action_search);
            this.SearchView = item.ActionView.JavaCast<Android.Widget.SearchView> ();

            return true;
        }

        [More un-related code]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there - my VS doesn't recognize `Android.Widget.SearchView` - how did you get that to work?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a shot in the dark here, try changing your namespace to lower case.

So from:

```
way:actionViewClass="Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView"
```

To:

```
way:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

Answer (score 0):

menu_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

MyActivity.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Toolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
using SearchView = Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView;

namespace Project.Sources.Features
{
    [Activity(Label = "")]
    public class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.search_activity);

            var _toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);


            //Se setea la actionbar
            _toolbar.SetNavigationIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);
            SetSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
            //SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            //SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        }

        SearchView _searchView;
        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_search, menu);

            var item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_search);

            var searchItem = MenuItemCompat.GetActionView(item);
             _searchView = searchItem.JavaCast<SearchView>();

            _searchView.SetIconifiedByDefault(true);

            _searchView.QueryTextChange += (s, e) =>
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Search: " + e.NewText, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            };

            _searchView.QueryTextSubmit += (s, e) =>
            {               
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Searched for: " + e.Query, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                e.Handled = true;
            };

            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Change the type FragmentActivity

```
public class TabActivity : FragmentActivity
```

to AppCompatActivity

```
public class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity
```

I´m using the Android.Support.V7.Widget package and work for me.

Comment: Could you explain what change(s) your code has that fix the questioner's issue?